# AWS: How to Add Another Couchbase Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I am trying to add a second node to my Couchbase 2.1.1 cluster on EC2.  However when I attempt to add a new server under

```
Server Nodes > Active Server > Add Server
```

I get the following error

```
Attention - Failed to reach erlang port mapper. 
Could not connect to "172.31.49.78" on port "4369". 
This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a 
firewall in place between the servers
```

Another odd thing I noticed is that the second Couchbase instance has a blank public dns.  I created it with the "More like this" wizard in the AWS management console.  What should I try next?  Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When I want to add a new node to the cluster I open up the web admin console on the new node and click the join cluster option, adding the ip of the current node and the relevant user and password.

You are most likely having the issue because you haven't opened up port 4369 as stated in the error on both nodes, they are needed for node to node configuration.  Change your security group on aws to allow this for both nodes.

Visit this link to see which ports you need for node to node and client to node http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#network-ports

Comment: Thanks, Im going to try that now.  One thing though that I havent quite figured out is my new CB instance does not have a public DNS.  literally its blank in the console.  Could that have been because I set it up with a "more like this" button?

Comment: Oh and the reason I mention is because the way I currently know how to login is via the public dns entry.

Comment: What is the instance state in your aws dashboard? You didn't start this in a virtual private cloud did you?  If the instance is running and you are sure it is not in a private cloud then I would delete that instance and launch a new server.  Then make sure the correct ports are open.

Comment: @David Williams if you did not configured your cluster with dns names (not ip), you won't be able to add another instance by amazon public dns. And I prefer to create ebs backup before couchbase install and launch new instances from that snapshot, because couchbase stores some node preferences like ip, and when you "clone" instances it tries to run with incorrect config.

Comment: I usally take an clean AMI with some distibution, install all what I need except couchbase, save EBS snapshot and then I launch new instances from that snapshot.

Comment: I just launched a new micro, I automatically received a public dns.

Comment: In case you do not know this document from AWS community: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/running-couchbase-on-aws-new-white-paper.html  (not directly related to your question but globally interesting to all Couchbase on AWS)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend starting with a fresh instance and installing CB onto it, then going through the process yourself. I don't believe in "pre-cooked" solutions when it is just as easy to set it up on your own.

I have three Couchbase clusters running on AWS, and have had no issues. That being said, I also have my machines configured in a VPC, and resolve to one another using the Hosts file on the machine, but your situation may be different.  You'll need to make sure your AWS security groups are configured correctly, whatever network topology you decide upon.